# Using tf.dataset API in training cant get the whole data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tf.dataset to fetch images, labels, edges in training with GPU. But I find the dataset API cannot load all the data. 
I use codes:

```
def get_dataset(filenames, shuffle_buffer, repeat_times, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([filenames])
    dataset = dataset.map(tfrecord_preprocess)
    if repeat_times is None:
        dataset = dataset.repeat()
    else:
        dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat_times)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).batch(batch_size)
    return dataset

def tfrecord_preprocess(example):
    feature = {"image": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
               "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
               "edge": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value="")}
    parsed_feature = tf.parse_single_example(example, feature)

    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_feature["image"], out_type=tf.uint8)
    label = tf.decode_raw(parsed_feature["label"], out_type=tf.uint8)
    edge = tf.decode_raw(parsed_feature["edge"], out_type=tf.uint8)

    image = tf.cast(tf.reshape(image, shape=[1, 128, 128]), tf.float32) 
    label = tf.cast(tf.reshape(label, shape=[1, 128, 128]), tf.float32)
    edge = tf.cast(tf.reshape(edge, shape=[128, 128]), tf.float32)
    return image, label, edge
```

I write a simple codes to test the API

```
dataset = get_dataset(filenames, shuffle_buffer, repeat_times, batchsize)
#shuffle=1000, repeat_times=2, batchsize=13
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator
images, labels, edges = iter.get_next()
count = 0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in xrange(40):
        try:
            edges_value = sess.run(edges)
            count = count+len(edges_value)
            print count
        except tf.errors.OutofRangeError:
            break
```

the number of data is 260 so after repeat and batch, the epochs should be 40. It works.

However, when I use similar code for training, the total number of data is less than 260, only 140(through the var count). Does anyone know haw to solve this problem? Pls help me.

I use tensorflow-gpu 1.4

my training code is:

```
shuffle_buffer = params["shuffle_buffer"] #1000
repeat_times = params["repeat_times"] #1
batch_size = params["batch_size"] #26
num_classes = params["num_classes"] #2

dataset = model.get_dataset(filenames, shuffle_buffer, repeat_times, batch_size)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.device('/gpu:1'): 
    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()    
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(params["learning_rate"], 
                                           global_step, 100, 0.99)    
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

    images, labels, edges = iterator.get_next()
    _, probs = model.interence(features=images, training=True)
    loss, reg = model.get_loss(probs, labels, edges, num_classes)
    _, acc_mean, _ = model.get_acc(probs, labels)

    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    variables_average = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.99, global_step)
    var_list = tf.trainable_variables(scope='.*(kernel|bias)')
    variables_average_op = variables_average.apply(var_list)    

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        train_all_op = tf.group(train_op, variables_average_op)

tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
tf.summary.scalar("reg", reg)
tf.summary.scalar("acc_mean", acc_mean)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=5)

config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True,
                        allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
count = 0
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run() 
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./train', sess.graph)
    for _ in xrange(10):
        try:
            edges_value = sess.run(edges)
            count = count+len(edges_value)
            _, step, summary = sess.run([train_all_op, global_step, merged])
            writer.add_summary(summary, step)
            if step % 5 == 0:
                loss_value = sess.run(loss)
                print loss_value
                acc_mean_value = sess.run(acc_mean)
                print acc_mean_value
                saver.save(sess, params["save_dir"], step)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print "end of data"
            break
    print count
    print "the final step is %d" % step
    loss_value = sess.run(loss)
    print loss_value
    acc_mean_value = sess.run(acc_mean)
    print acc_mean_value
    saver.save(sess, params["save_dir"], step)    
    writer.close()
```

finally I got info in the terminal:

```
end of data
130
the final step is 5
```

to test the code I set the repeat times 1

But I use test codes:

```
def test():
    dataset = get_dataset("train_output.tfrecords", 1000, 1, 26)
    terator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    images, labels, edges = iterator.get_next()

    count = 0
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for i in xrange(10):
            try:
                images_value, labels_value, edges_value = sess.run([images, labels, edges])
                count = count+len(edges_value)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print "end of data"

        print count
        print i

test()
```

The terminal shows:

```
260
9
```

Comment: Just a note: you are calculating epochs as `260 rows * 2 repeats / 13 batch_size = 40`. That's the number of batches, not the number of epochs. The number of epochs is 2. An epoch is one full traversal of the data.

Comment: When you say that your data is less than 260, only 140, what do you mean? Is it intentionally 140 or when you train is it only finding 140 then stopping? Posting your training code (or some minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue) would help. Only having what works doesn't let us identify where there may be a difference between your working example and the "similar training code" that does not work.

Comment: I mean it is only finding 140 and then stopping. I edited my question, and now it seems more clear. Thank you.

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks. Will take a look.

Comment: Ok, think I've got it figured out. Give this a shot for me to verify since I don't have your model and can't verify. If it works, I'll write up an answer explaining what was happening for you to accept. Remove this line `edges_value = sess.run(edges)` in your try. I expect that when you do so you'll see the final step be 10 instead of 5. Please verify.

Comment: As a note, I realize that won't let you see the edges_count as you'd like; however, if the steps do indeed go up to 10 then we can get the edges_count to show in a different way that won't cause the problem.

Comment: I try your advice. It really works. Thank you very much! The api will load the data again. I think if i want to get the edges length, maybe I need to sess.run(edges) first and then set it into tf.placeholders to feed the train_op?

Comment: Added an answer. Please take a look and give it a try. This was a really fun problem to help you with. I love TensorFlow.

Comment: Did the suggestion in the answer work for you? If so I'd appreciate it if you'd mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `sess.run(edges)` is causing this part of the graph to execute again: `images, labels, edges = iterator.get_next()`. Therefore, everytime you run it, you are consuming one iteration that is not counted in your counter.

To get the count of edges, keep a counter inside of the `with tf.device('/gpu:1')` block. You can even graph it on tensorboard using a `tf.summary.scalar` similar to how you do so with `loss`.

Declare a `edges_count = tf.Variable(1, name='edges_count', trainable=False, dtype=tf.int32)`

```
images, labels, edges = iterator.get_next()
edges_count_update_op = tf.assign_add(edges_count, len(edges))
```

Then add `edges_count_update_op` to your train_op group.